# How main bars are placed in this picture? Paralle to traffic or perpendicular

Tags: deck

In a deck of simply span bridge of 24ft length and width of 34ft [image]

Comment: VTC - It really is unclear what you are attempting to ask here.

Comment: This doesn't look like a DIY project.  You're going to need a lot oof expertise to answer any questions like this.

Comment: It is perfectly clear to me that the bars are perpendicular to the traffic. I have a degree in civil engineering and reading this sketch is not difficult at all.

Comment: The diagram shows only the bridge deck and piers.  The structure that carries the bridge deck must obviously span the piers (duh). So it will be either parallel to traffic or perpendicular to the piers, depending on cost given the angle of the bridge.  Are you trying to BS your way through school? You'll *seriously* regret that later.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that big and carrying a load (you said "traffic") is deep in the "licensed structural engineer" category. Don't ask about it on the internet, find someone with a suitable university degree, license from the local authorities, and quite a bit of experience building bridges.

No, this person will not be cheap. But neither will that bridge.